# Call RegisterClassObjects and ResumeClassObjects in multiple threads?

Tags: interface, com, atl

I have a C++ COM server that uses a third-party dll which also exposes a COM interface. The third-party dll is old (built with Visual Studio 6) so it uses old ATL code. I have the source for this dll.

I'm in the process of making my application work as 32- and 64-bit, so I need to update the third-party dll to make it operate with my 64-bit application. Of course, the old ATL code isn't supported under recent versions of Visual Studio so I have to modify it. I basically made one change - the module in the dll was derived from the old CComModule. I changed that to CAtlExeModuleT<>. I got that working so the COM interface exposed by the third-party dll works correctly, but now none of my application's COM interfaces are visible.

CoRegisterClassObjects() and CoResumeClassObjects() are called from the third-party dll (in one thread) and from my application (in a different thread). I don't get any errors returned from those...but is that a valid scenario?

If I do not call CoRegisterClassObjects() and CoResumeClassObjects() from the third-party dll, my application's COM interfaces are visible.

So it seems that one hides the other. However, this worked correctly using the third-party dll built with Visual Studio 6.

Is there any reason that only one set of interfaces would be visible?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue. It turns out that recent versions of ATL still support the CComModule class. Unfortunately, I can't recall all the details that made me change the class I was using. But the CComModule::Init() method was one of them. It takes a third, optional GUID parameter, that wasn't being passed in. Maybe the older Visual Studio 6 ATL code had another way of getting this value. The newer ATL code didn't get the value. I added that parameter and things started working again.